# Numba acceleration on nested funtions

Tags: python, numba

I have tried to use numba to [accelerate lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54359670/use-numba-on-lambda-function) but I failed to do so. Seems like lambda is not supported by numba. So I rewrote the lambda function as def functions. I am constructing an implicit function f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2-z^2 and some others, which will only be evaluated once after construction. xi,yi,zi are for translation of the implicit function.

```
def wrapperNode(xi,yi,zi,R):

    @nb.jit(nopython=True)
    def Node(x,y,z):
        x = xi - x
        y = yi - y
        z = zi - z
        return x**2 + y**2 - z**2

    return Node

import time
for i in range(10):
    Start = time.time()
    Node = wrapperNode(i+1.0,i+2.0,i+3.0,i+4.0)
    a = Node(1.0,2.0,3.0)
    Final = time.time()
    print(Final-Start)
```

Time result for each loop:

```
0.137923002243042
0.14062094688415527
0.14144468307495117
0.1332840919494629
0.12716078758239746
0.14055514335632324
0.14062023162841797
0.1423487663269043
0.14061713218688965
0.1943662166595459
```

It was actually much slower than simply evaluate the Node function in the wrapper function. Every time I changed the input arguments for the wrapper function, the computer has to compile the Node function if I evaluate it. So no acceleration at all...I am looking for a way to accelerate the entire wrapper function. If anyone has any idea, please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is not only the compilation, it is also the dispatching of the "jitted" function.

It is not worth to use numba jit for such a simple function with just scalar components. If the arguments were arrays of data and the operation was to be performed in a vectorial way it would make sense... but only when as the number of elements grows.

In numba you have two overheads:
1. Compilation
2. Dispatching (a given function may have different compiled versions based on the types of the arguments, so a type signature for the call has to be done, a check on an internal dictionary is done based on that signature, the arguments are unboxed and the actual call is done). This takes a non-negligible amount of time. So you need a function that is complex enough to amortise this time

Rule of thumb: it wont work for trivial code that has no loop, either explicit (for, while...) or implicit (vector code better handled via @numba.vectorize).

Comment: Very helpful explanation. My code actually takes vectors as input. But it is still a very simple function. I am voxelizing the implicit function to produce solid geometry and trying to make the voxelization faster. Seems no other solutions......

Comment: Even if it is pretty simple, as long as it is over a large number of elements, it may work fine with numba. Just bear in mind that numba is efficient on NumPy arrays. Have your code work on NumPy arrays first. You may even be able to get OK performance just using NumPy. Then you may move the code to numba to get C-like performance if done properly.

I would avoid the wrapper node thing. Just pass a couple of vectors to the function. You probably want to put the arguments together in a NumPy array.

I am sorry, but without extra code I can't put a better example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the cache to avoid recompiling each time that you call the function

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True,cache=True)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the advice. But it didn't work. It is still much slower than the lambda function and direct evaluation.